# smarty template compile directory not writable

Tags: templates, unix, smarty, fedora, chmod

i'm using the latest version of smarty (3.0rc3).
i made my  templates_c directory writable in command line (chmod -R 777 templates_c) but smarty still outputs this when i call $smart->utility->testInstall();

```
Testing compile directory...
FAILED: ./php/classes/smarty/templates_c/ is not writable.
Warning: rename(/tmp/wrtub1GxS,./php/classes/smarty/templates_c
```

and this when i use smarty

```
/73e0ecf25f1c14182b8af5906bb8e9afa33b2b07.file.main.html.php): 
Permission denied in /var/www/html/dev/dynamic/php/classes/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 41 
Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory 
in /var/www/html/dev/dynamic/php/classes/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php
```

here is my ls -al output

```
drwxrwxrwx. 8 cove   cove    4096 Aug 31 15:53 .
drwxrwxr-x. 5 cove   cove    4096 Aug 31 15:24 ..
drwxrwxrwx. 2 cove   cove    4096 Aug 31 15:36 cache
drwxrwxrwx. 2 cove   cove    4096 Aug 31 15:39 configs
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 cove   cove    2810 Aug 31 15:22 debug.tpl
drwxrwxrwx. 2 cove   cove    4096 Jul 15 01:09 plugins
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 cove   cove   27135 Aug 31 15:45 Smarty.class.php
drwxrwxrwx. 2 cove   cove    4096 Jul 15 01:09 sysplugins
drwxrwxrwx. 2 cove   cove    4096 Aug 31 15:36 templates
drwxrwxrwx. 2 nobody nobody  4096 Aug 31 15:53 templates_c
```

i'm working on fedora 13. can someone please help me.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

this is the solution in my case:
deactivate selinux 
in terminal type system-config-selinux
good luck

Comment: you are right, removing some selinux-policy, policycoreutils and libselinux-python did the job. thanks!